# Mojo::UserAgent and progress bar

Tags: perl, progress-bar

Does the [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) have something similar to the [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) `show_progress` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible to do a `show_progress` similar to `LWP::UserAgent`  using `Mojo::UserAgent`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make progress bar with help of [progress event from Mojo::Message](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Message#progress)

```
$| = 1;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->on(start => sub {
    my ($ua, $tx) = @_;

    $tx->req->once(finish => sub {
        $tx->res->on(progress => sub {
            my $msg = shift;
            return unless my $len = $msg->headers->content_length;
            my $size = $msg->content->progress;
            print "\rProgress: ", $size == $len ? 100 : int($size / ($len / 100)), '%';
        });
    });
});

my $tx = $ua->get($url);
print $tx->error ? "\nDownloading failed: ".$tx->error->{message} : "\nDownloading finished!\n";
```